# TypeError: setOpenModal is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, typeerror, react-props

I am trying to make a login modal popup which will show on click of a button inside of a navbar. However, I am getting below error:

TypeError: setOpenModal is not a function

Even after looking at many threads here, I am unable to understand what is causing the error in my case. Below is my code:

Navbar.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Navbar.css";
import Login from "./Login";

function Navbar() {

  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);

  const showModal = () => {
    setOpenModal(true);
  };

  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <div className="nav-div">
        <Link to="/" className="nav-logo">
          <i class="fas fa-hamburger"></i>Hungermania
        </Link>
        <div className="nav-form">
          <form>
            <input
              className="nav-search"
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search for your favorite restaurant, cuisine or a dish"
            ></input>
            <button className="btn-search">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <button className="login-btn nav-link" onClick={showModal}>
              Login
            </button>
            {openModal && <Login setOpenModal={setOpenModal} />}
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <button className="signup-btn nav-link">Sign Up</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Login.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Login.css";

function Login({ setOpenModal }) {
  const hideModal = () => {
    setOpenModal(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="modalBackground">
      <div className="modalContainer">
        <div className="titleclosebtn">
          <button onClick={hideModal}>&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div className="title">
          <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="body">
          <form>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" required />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label for="phone">Phone No:</label>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Phone No." required />
            <br />
            <br />
            <label for="email">Email Id:</label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email@domain.com" required />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div className="footer">
              <button type="submit" class="btn-signup">
                SIGN UP
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: When exactly do you get this error? When you're trying to close the modal or when opening it? Also, which version of `react` are you using?

Comment: When I click the navbar login button, no modal shows up besides a gray block at the corner of the screen. But if i add this Login component to the Home component where i have added other components like navbar, herosection, cards etc., only the modal popup appears instead of the original home page. And after closing the modal, i am getting this error.

Comment: Also, i am using react version 17.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with ur code, so it was prob cash or something.

restarting server should stop accusing that error.

Normally when stupid errors like this happens, i just comment that part that is accusing error, wait refresh and uncomment, that works too instead of always restarting server.

Answer (score 0):

`{openModal && <Login setOpenModal={setOpenModal} />}`

this part of the code. You are passing down a prop named `setOpenModal` and you are passing down `setOpenModal`. You cannot pass down the setter of your state. You can either pass down variables or functions with props. So create a function, in that function you can use `setOpenModal` and then pass that function down like this:

```
const someFunction=(value)=>{
   setOpenModal(value);
}


{openModal && <Login whatEverName={someFunction} />}
```

Comment: I tried this but it caused the close button to stop functioning. @Sobhan

Comment: Could you post the code?